# How am I getting more entries in my table than the length of my for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I don't think the context matters too much for question but basically I have this simple for loop in MATLAB:

```
count4 = 1;
for m = 405:-1:3
    end_value = metrics(smallest_row, m);
    rpath(count4) = end_value;
    smallest_row = end_value + 1;
    count4 = count4 + 1;
end
```

So from what I understand, `m` goes from 405 to 3 in this loop.
My `metrics` table is of size 8x405, and so I'm only using the values from 3-405 inclusive, which should mean there are 403 entries for `rpath`, right?
So how come there are 404 entries for `rpath`? Where is the other entry coming from?
`count4` ends at a value of 404 which should presumably mean there are 403 entries as well as `count4 = count4 + 1` is the last thing that happens in the loop?

Comment: Context is always important. What was the value of `rpath` before the loop starts? It is always a good idea to [preallocate arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Please read [mre], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo rpath didn't exist before the loop started. I didn't want to preallocate the array as I don't understand why it's the size it is. If I preallocate it as zeros then it's difficult to see why rpath is as it is because the data I'm using includes zeros.

Comment: Then preallocate as NaN. `rpath = nan(403,1)`. Unless you have a statement `rpath=[]` before the loop, or this code is inside a function and there's nothing assigned to `rpath` at all, you cannot be sure `rpath` didn't exist. Because you don't give context, I'm going to assume `rpath` wasn't empty. I don't think there's a better explanation for what you're seeing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! You were right, I'd pre allocated as 0's before, then deleted it but I didn't have any clear at the start of my code so it was still initialised from the time before it. Next time I post I'll try and provide context